# Where is modelBuilder.IncludeMetadataInDatabase in EF CTP5?

Tags: entity-framework-4

With CTP4, I used to be able to do the following (as [suggested by ptrandem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600672/entity-framework-ctp4-code-first-how-to-turn-off-the-automatic-pluralizati/3655335#3655335)):

```
modelBuilder.IncludeMetadataInDatabase = false
```

With this line of code, EF doesn't create the EdmMetadata table in my database, and doesn't track model changes.

I was unable to find a way to accomplish this in the new CTP5, so now every time I change my model, I get this:

> The model backing the 'MyContext'
>   context has changed since the database
>   was created. Either manually
>   delete/update the database, or call
>   Database.SetInitializer with an
>   IDatabaseInitializer instance. For
>   example, the
>   DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges
>   strategy will automatically delete and
>   recreate the database, and optionally
>   seed it with new data.

So, does everybody know where is the IncludeMetadataInDatabase property in CTP5? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CTP5 includes a very cool feature called *Pluggable Conventions* that can be used to Add/Remove conventions. `IncludeMetadataInDatabase` has been removed and being replaced with a
pluggable convention that does the same thing for you:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions
            .Remove<System.Data.Entity.Database.IncludeMetadataConvention>();
```

Comment: Thanks, Morteza. Do you know if there are any other differences between doing this, and just dropping the EdmMetadata table as the ADO.NET team blog states? What is preferable?

Comment: No problem. I think the one you found on team's blog is talking about existing databases and the one I suggested is for when you are generating a DB from your object model. At the end of the day they both have a same result: you have a POCO object model that works with a  database without a Metadata table so I think it depends on your scenario (a brand new database or an existing one).

Comment: In latest release, this got moved to modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IncludeMetadataConvention>();

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent in CTP5 to switch off initializer logic: In your Application_Start in Global.asax, enter the following:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.DbDatabase.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(null);
```

Answer (score 3):

In EF 4.1

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have been looking for this all over, and I had to find the answer right after posting my question, DUH. Right from the [ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-walkthrough.aspx):

> In CTP5 we have removed the need to
>   perform additional configuration when
>   mapping to an existing database. If
>   Code First detects that it is pointing
>   to an existing database schema that it
>   did not create then it will ‘trust
>   you’ and attempt to use code first
>   with the schema. The easiest way to
>   point Code First to an existing
>   database is to add a App/Web.config
>   connection string with the same name
>   as your derived DbContext (...)