# Entity Framework Code First MySql Pluralizing Tables

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco

I am using the Microsoft Entity Framework with code first to manage my data (with MySQL). I have defined a POCO object, however, when I try to add data it says table Users doesn't exist. I looked in the DB and it created table User not Users. How can I remedy this? It is driving me nuts!

Thanks!

```
  public class User
 {
    [Key,Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20), Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30), Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100), Required]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what connector and version are you using? this seems to come in at that level.. could be wrong though

Comment: Hey mysql connector net 6.3.7

Comment: Also if I add [Table("User")] above the classit works but id rather not have to do that

Comment: sorry I cant find the post i read a while ago, but this looks like it might have some ways of affecting pluralisation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600672/entity-framework-ctp4-code-first-how-to-turn-off-the-automatic-pluralizatio

Comment: also these guys have another connecter that is not free but does have a trial which if you can be bothered you could try to identify if its a contributing factor: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/download.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used MySQL with EF yet but regardless I think the solution is unbias.  You need to turn off Pluralize Table Convention.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.Edm.Db;

public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {    
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Now EF will look for the literal of your object name to the table name.

Some great video tutorials are at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723 under the Continue Learning Entity Framework.  For additional learning experience, you can not specify the above but rather explicitly map the object 'user' to the table 'user'.

Additional References:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/14/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Gotta give it to you because the clear explanation and the link! Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder dbModelBuilder)
        {
            dbModelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put an attribute on the class telling the name of the table:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    //...
}
```

...or you could use the fluent API. To do this you will override the OnModelCreating method in your DbContext class.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Map(t => t.ToTable("Users"));
    }
}
```

In future versions of EF, we've been promised the ability to write our own conventions. Thats not in there yet as of version 4.1...

(Haven't tried it with MySQL...)